# Log from Symfony to php://stdout shows log messages in my console commands

Tags: php, symfony, logging

I am running a docker container with the official `php:7.3.3-apache` tag. I have Symfony 4 installed with monolog enabled.

Normally monolog uses the `var/dev.log`, `var/prod.log` and `var/test.log` to write its logs but you can change the configuration to `php://stdout` or `php://stderr` to send the logs to the docker container.

My monolog.yaml file looks like:

```
monolog:
    handlers:
        main:
            type: stream
            path: "php://stdout"
            level: debug
            channels: ["!event"]
        console:
            type: console
            process_psr_3_messages: false
            channels: ["!event", "!doctrine", "!console"]
```

And it sends the logs properly from the website, however when I run a command using the `php bin/console` command I get the logs right on the screen, for example:

```
$ php bin/console cache:clear

[2019-06-24 14:29:19] doctrine.DEBUG: SELECT h0_.id AS id_0, h0_.name AS name_1, h0_.value AS value_2, h0_.description AS description_3 FROM hpa_configuration h0_ [] []
[2019-06-24 14:29:19] php.INFO: User Deprecated: The "Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Command\ContainerAwareCommand" class is deprecated since Symfony 4.2, use "Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command" with dependency injection instead. {"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): User Deprecated: The \"Symfony\\Bundle\\FrameworkBundle\\Command\\ContainerAwareCommand\" class is deprecated since Symfony 4.2, use \"Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Command\\Command\" with dependency injection instead. at /var/www/html/hpa/vendor/symfony/framework-bundle/Command/ContainerAwareCommand.php:18)"} []

 // Clearing the cache for the dev environment with debug ......
```

How can I log properly from the website and commands?

Comment: Hi! Did you finally find any solution for this issue? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Change `php://stdout` to `php://stderr`

Comment: Already tried, with the docker image of php 7.3.3 they both go to the same place